# Database design, adding an extra column versus converting existing column with a function

Tags: python, mysql, django

suppose there was  a database table with one column, and it's a PK. To make things more specific this is a django project and the database is in mysql.

If I needed an additional column with all unique values, should I create a new UniqueField with unique integers, or just write a hash-like function to convert the existing PK's for each existing row (model instance) into a new unique variable. The current PK is a varchar/ & string.

With creating a new column it consumes more memory but I think writing a new function and converting fields frequently has disadvantages also. Any ideas?

Comment: A primary key cannot have duplicates - that's one of its properties. So what exactly are you trying to do? A row is not a model (a table is the closest equivalent). A row would be an _instance_ of the model. Perhaps you should describe the problem you are trying to solve instead of asking for help with your solution.

Comment: My current PK is a large-ish string, I just want to know the cost/benefits of using a PK like that versus just converting it into a hash-like number that is also unique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having a string-valued PK should not be a problem in any modern database system. A PK is automatically indexed, so when you perform a look-up with a condition like `table1.pk = 'long-string-key'`, it won't be a string comparison but an index look-up. So it's ok to have string-valued PK, regardless of the length of the key values.

In any case, if you need an additional column with all unique values, then I think you should just add a new column.